# Longest Palindromic Subsequence Multithread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, palindrome

I'm trying to learn how to multithread with c, and thought that the [longest palindromic subsequence problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-subsequence-dp-12/) would be a good place to start.

The idea is that we run two threads and compare their results to find the answer. One thread deals with "odd" subsequences, the other with "even" ones.

Although the code below seems to work, my question is: Could it be better in some way? E.g. reduce space complexity or time complexity while retaining the general idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct str{
  char* seq;
  int len;
};

void *odd(void* arg){
  struct str index = *(struct str*)arg;
  int maxAns = 1;
  for(int i = 1; i < index.len; i++){
    int low = i - 1;
    int high = i + 1;
    int currMax = 1;
    while(low >= 0 && high < index.len && index.seq[low] == index.seq[high]){
      low--;
      high++;
      currMax=currMax+2;
    }
    if(currMax > maxAns){
      maxAns = currMax;
    }
  }
  int* res = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *res = maxAns;
  free(arg);
  return (void*)res;
}

void *even(void* arg){
  struct str index = *(struct str*)arg;
  int maxAns = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < index.len; i++){
    int low = i;
    int high = i + 1;
    int currMax = 0;
    while(low >= 0 && high < index.len && index.seq[low] == index.seq[high]){
      low--;
      high++;
      currMax=currMax+2;
    }
    if(currMax > maxAns){
      maxAns = currMax;
    }
  }
  int* res = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *res = maxAns;
  free(arg);
  return (void*)res;
}

int main(void){

  char seq0[] = "aaasaaasadaadsdafa";
  int len = sizeof(seq0)/sizeof(seq0[0])-1;

  struct str* s0 = malloc(sizeof(struct str));
  struct str* s1 = malloc(sizeof(struct str));
  s0->seq = (char*)seq0;
  s1->seq = (char*)seq0;
  s0->len = len;
  s1->len = len;

  pthread_t t0;
  pthread_t t1;
  int* res0;
  int* res1;
  if (pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &odd, s0)!=0){
    return 0;
  }
  if (pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &even, s1)!=0){
    return 00;
  }
  if(pthread_join(t0, (void**)&res0)!=0){
    return 1;
  }
  if(pthread_join(t1, (void**)&res1)!=0){
    return 11;
  }

  if(*res0 > *res1){
    printf("%d\n", *res0);
  }else{
    printf("%d\n", *res1);
  }

  free(s0);
  free(s1);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: here is a new version with some improvements as suggested.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// main prog
struct str{
  char* seq;
  int len;
};

void *odd(void* arg){
  const struct str *index = arg;
  int maxAns = 1;
  for(int i = 1; i < index->len; i++){
    int low = i - 1;
    int high = i + 1;
    int currMax = 1;
    while(low >= 0 && high < index->len && index->seq[low] == index->seq[high]){
      low--;
      high++;
      currMax=currMax+2;
    }
    if(currMax > maxAns){
      maxAns = currMax;
    }
  }

  return (void *)(intptr_t)maxAns;
}

void *even(void* arg){
  const struct str *index = arg;
  int maxAns = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < index->len; i++){
    int low = i;
    int high = i + 1;
    int currMax = 0;
    while(low >= 0 && high < index->len && index->seq[low] == index->seq[high]){
      low--;
      high++;
      currMax=currMax+2;
    }
    if(currMax > maxAns){
      maxAns = currMax;
    }
  }

  return (void *)(intptr_t)maxAns;
}

// timer
long timediff(clock_t t1, clock_t t2) {
    long elapsed;
    elapsed = ((double)t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000000;
    return elapsed;
}

int main(void){
  // timer
  clock_t ti1, ti2;
  long elapsed;

  ti1 = clock();

  // main program
  char seq[] = "aaasadsdafasdhjkagsdfjhasjbjflASHBFHJASKBHFKJASBFASSDHJGVAHDGVsakhjfdsakjfuadsfk";
  int len = sizeof(seq)/sizeof(seq[0])-1;

  struct str s = {seq, len};

  pthread_t t0;
  pthread_t t1;
  intptr_t res0;
  intptr_t res1;
  if (pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &odd, &s)!=0){
    return 0;
  }
  if (pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &even, &s)!=0){
    return 00;
  }
  if(pthread_join(t0, (void*)&res0)!=0){
    return 1;
  }
  if(pthread_join(t1, (void*)&res1)!=0){
    return 11;
  }

  printf("%d\n", (int)(res0 > res1 ? res0 : res1));

  // end timer
  ti2 = clock();
  elapsed = timediff(ti1, ti2);
  printf("elapsed: %ld microseconds\n", elapsed);
  return 0;
}

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Passing strings to threads

You are dynamically allocating `struct str`s and passing pointers to those structs to the threads. However, the structs could be allocated on the stack instead:

```
struct str s0 = {seq0, len};
...
if (pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &odd, &s0) != 0) {
```

Note that you also don't need two different instances of it; the threads are not modifying the strings, so they can both get a pointer to `s0`.

Inside `odd()` and `even()`, you are making a copy of `s0` and `s1`. This is unnecessary. I would write the following:

```
void *odd(void *arg) {
    const struct str *index = arg;
    int maxAns = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < index->len; i++) {
        ...
```

But you don't actually need to know the length of the string up front. Instead of using `struct str`, I would just pass a pointer to the string directly:

```
if (pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &odd, seq0) != 0) {
```

And then just check in the `for` and `while` loops whether you hit the terminating NUL character:

```
void *odd(void* arg){
    const char *str = arg;
    ...
    for (int i = 1; str[i]; i++) {
        ...
        while(low >= 0 && str[high] && str[low] == str[high]) {
            ...
```

## Returning the answer without allocating memory

While the return type of a thread function should be `void *`, you can actually make it return an integer if you are careful. Make use of the fact that you can cast a pointer to and from [`intptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071200/what-is-the-use-of-intptr-t):

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
void *odd(void *arg) {
    ...
    return (void *)(intptr_t)maxAns;
}
```

The answer is first cast to `intptr_t` before casting it to a `void *`; it is possible to do it without the first cast but your compiler might complain then.

To read the result, write:

```
intptr_t res0;
intptr_t res1;
...
if (pthread_join(t0, (void *)&res0) != 0) {
    ...
}
...
printf("%d\n", (int)(res0 > res1 ? res0 : res1));
```

This, combined with the other way of passing strings means you don't have to do any manual memory management anymore, and you got rid of the memory leaks you had in your code.

## Optimizing the code

A lot of CPUs nowadays have more than 2 cores. If you had very large strings to process, you probably want to use all available cores instead of just two. In that case, the best strategy would probably to use a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool), and split up the task of finding the largest palindrome in a way so there are many small tasks. For example, split it up based on the position of the first character, or the middle one like you already have done inside `odd()` and `even()`.

Then, consider that we are not interested in small palindromes, only the longer one, so if we know we found the largest palindrome, we can stop searching for other possibilities. So make it so we first check the largest possible palindrome: `i` should be in the middle of the string. Use an [atomic variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) to store the size of the largest palindrome found so far; if a new task starts it checks what the maximum size is of the palindrome it can search for (this depends on `i`), if this is lower that the maximum so far it can just immediately return.

There might be other algorithms possible for finding the longest palindrome subsequence, see [this Computer Science question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/fastest-algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-palindrome-subsequence). Last but not least, you might be able to further optimize it by using [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD), but this is outside the C standard.

## Exit codes

You wrote these return statements when something went wrong with thread creation or joining:

```
return 0;
return 00;
return 1;
return 11;
```

That's very strange. The first two `return` statements will cause the program to exit with exit code 0, which normally means success. You want to return a non-zero exit code in all these cases. It's also good practice to return [`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) instead of hardcoded numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## `malloc()` can return a null pointer

> ```
>   int* res = malloc(sizeof(int));
>   *res = maxAns;
> ```

We need to ensure `res` is not null and not dereference it if so.

(To those who say "it always succeeds on my platform": it probably doesn't, when you use a more constrained `ulimit -v`, so get in the habit of coding robustly.

---

## Pointless cast

> ```
>   return (void*)res;
> ```

We can just `return res`, since any object-pointer can be assigned to `void*`.

---

## Consider using a higher-level interface

Using `<pthread.h>` can be good for understanding, and if that's your main interest, by all means continue.

However, using a higher-level abstraction can give you more for less effort, and many compilers these days offer support for OpenMP.  That lets you easily distribute work across available cores, and use dynamic scheduling when the work items vary in size.